# Object class change in quanteda::corpus

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining, quanteda

I am having a problem with running a script that I wrote a few weeks ago and it was running with no errors then. The script was to read a few thousands of files and create a corpus from them. But now, I don't know why, the same code returns a different class of object at the beginning of script and as a result, following sections of the code break.

The documents I want to read are international treaties. Before, when I applied quanteda::corpus, it returned S3 corpus list objects under "Data" in the global environment. But now, when I apply the function, I get corpus class character objects under "Values".

Here is a sample from the code aimed at reading only one treaty to illustrate the problem:

```
> #This is the link to the file to be read: 
> [https://investmentpolicy.unctad.org/international-investment-agreements/treaty-files/5908/download][1]

> mar_jp_txt<- readtext("/Desktop/mar_jp.pdf")
> corpus_txt_mjp <- corpus(mar_jp_txt) %>%
  corpus_reshape(to = "sentences")

> class(corpus_txt_mjp)
[1] "corpus"    "character"
```

However, I have a previously saved workspace image and there I have the `corpus_txt_mjp` object too. When I check its class, it is different:

```
> class(corpus_txt_mjp)
[1] "corpus" "list"
```

Considering that I started this project the last October, I should be using the same version of quanteda since then. Yet, even though I have changed nothing in the script, I get a different outcome now. Back then I was running the script on small samples to see whether it works and when I try to run it on the entire sample now, I get this problem. What could be the reason for this and can someone please offer me a solution?

Many many thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I guess I realized the issue. I don't know why and how, but last month I was using an older version of quanteda. When I installed the recent version, the code stopped working. So in this case I should either install an older version or change the script according to the new version.

Comment: We can only solve the issue you are encountering if you include the code that breaks under the quanteda 2.x. Here you describe the object class but not the operation you are attempting that breaks.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the corpus object has changed in v2.0, from a list to character vector. However, you can run `as.corpus(corpus_txt_mjp)` to upgraded your object.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply Professor. But as I said, I started this project only a few months ago and the same script was returning a different outcome just a month ago. Besides, even if I apply as.corpus as you suggested, then I will have to change a lot of the following lines. Is there a way to coerce a standard corpus to a compressed corpus (opposite of as.corpus)?

Comment: If you run `attr(corpus_txt_mjp, "meta")$system`, you should can see the exact versions of quanteda and R. If it does not show anything, it must be before v2.0. The compressed corpus (corpuzip) is deprecated, by the way.